# "List of Corrections" is set as a `\section` instead of a `\chapter`

Tags: memoir, fixme

Below is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}
\usepackage{fixme}
\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
Oops?\fxwarning{Hello world!}

\listoffixmes

\end{document}
```

I want the title (List of Corrections) to be typeset as a chapter in my `\backmatter`. When I change the class to `scrbook` it *is* typeset as a chapter. Is there an easy fix?

Suggestions about using a better package than `fixme` (should there be any) are welcome in the comments. I just discovered this package and I'm not hell-bent on using this particular package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package doesn't support the `memoir` class.

You can fix `fixme` (pun intended) by making the appropriate choice:

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}
\usepackage{fixme}

% pretend we're in book.cls
\makeatletter
\let\@lox@prtc\@lox@prtc@book
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
Oops?\fxwarning{Hello world!}

\listoffixmes

\end{document}
```